# Procedural PHP Framework Concept

Tags: php, frameworks

So I had this idea to map my framework's folder structure to namespaces with a dynamic build process.

To give you an idea how this would work here an example structure:

```
src/
    FS/
       File/
            open.php (function)
    Math/
         add.php (function)
         test.php (function)
         MAGIC.php (constant)
```

Would be translated to:

```
namespace FS\File {
    function open() { /* ... */ }
}

namespace Math {
    function add() { /* ... */ }
    function test() { /* ... */ }
    const MAGIC = /* ... */;
}
```

There would be no support for classes.

A function would be defined as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * src/Math/add.php
 *
 * This is the Math\add module.
 */
return function($require) {
    // Require Math\test module.
    $test = $require('Math\test');

    return function($a, $b) use ($test) {
        // Call Math\test function
        $test($a, $b);

        return $a + $b;
    };
};
?>
```

The outer most function is for providing a new scope (so all previous defined variables are non existing).

Then the `$require` variable is for including other modules.

(The idea to require all other dependencies came from `node`. I think this would make mocking and testing a lot easier because one could test the module with an overwritten `$require` variable.)

And constants could be defined as follows:

```
<?php
/**
 * src/Math/MAGIC.php
 */
return 0xDEADBEEF;
?>
```

The whole framework would then have a `require` method to load a module from filesystem:

```
/**
 * Function that is responsible to load a module.
 */
function require($module) {
    static $loadedModules = [];

    $modFileName = str_replace('\\', '/', $module);

    // Check if already loaded or load from file system
    // ...
    // ...

    return $loadedModule;
}
```

So using Math\add would look like this:

```
require('Math\add')('require')(1, 2)
                   // ^- dependency loader function
```

Of course this does not look very nice so the build process would generate the namespaces and automatically fill in the require calls:

```
namespace Math {
    function add(...$args) {
        return require(__FUNCTION__)('require')(...$args);
    }

    /* Or constants ... */
    const MAGIC = 0xDEADBEEF;
}
```

Constants could be require'd in the same fashion as functions:

```
require('Math\MAGIC') // 0xDEADBEEF
// or through the generated namespace
Math\MAGIC // 0xDEADBEEF
```

The benefits I see:

- Flexible structure (namespaces are generated automatically).
- Easily mockable and testable.
- Clear dependencies (dependencies are always `require`'d)

But I can also see the danger of having too many variables because of the way dependencies are managed. Also I'm not too sure about the performance.

I have never seen such an architecture and I'm curious what others think of my concept.

Comment: Also worth noting: I've made a proof of concept so this is actually possible. I can put it on GitHub if anyone is interested to see my implementation.

Comment: Looks like you always have to write a lot of additional code, every one function call turns into three (if I counted correctly) and if I understand PHP correctly, every function call allocates new memory.

Comment: In theory it seems feasible. I'm not sure what benefit you have by having a build process define the structure for you though. Why not define it all as you need it from the start and skip then build?

Comment: @JimmyT. Yep, that's what I observed with blackfire.io as well.

Comment: `require` is a reserved word in PHP.

Answer (score -1):

It is hard to tell would it have any advantages at all. Probably the best thing is to make small project to see what are advantages/disadvantages using this method of code organization.